# Windows Proxy Server advice

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

I have a webserver that currently has about 10 IP addresses.  I have various clients that require a proxy server to route their internal traffic through.

The load is not that great, so I'd like to have this ONE server act as a proxy server for 10 different clients, each client having their own unique IP on the server.

The hardware is already setup, but I'm wondering what software solutions you guys recommend?

I've looked at WinGate, Squid-Proxy, etc...but am pretty green with this.  Maybe there's even a way to have Windows do this natively?

I'm running Windows Server 2008, 32 bit.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "10 different clients, each client having their own unique IP on the server"?

Comment: What I mean is this:  Client A.) will point all their internal computers to this proxy server, and they want their public IP to be unique to THEM.  Client B.) will point all their internal computers to the SAME server, but they want their public IP to be unique to them as well.  So Client A.) may have 10 internal machines, but they want their public IP to come from my server.  They also want to make sure this IP is just used by them.  Client B, although pointing to the same server, needs to have a UNIQUE public IP on that server as well.

Comment: So you want 10 public IPs? Why not give them directly to the clients, then?

Comment: Massimo, my response was too long so I posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a web proxy or "just" Internet access for your network?

If you only need network access, i.e. NAT your network behind your public IP address, you need just two network interfaces on the server, one connected to your private network and the other connected to your public one. Windows Server 2008 (as 2003 and 2000) has built-in support for NAT routing (and much more) via the **[Routing and Remote Access Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634(WS.10).aspx)**.

If you need a full web proxy solution, there are plenty of them around; the Microsoft one is, of course, **[ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx)**, which is a full-featured firewall/proxy; it may be a bit overkill for your needs, though.

Comment: Duplicated from comment above in case you missed it:

What I mean is this: Client A.) will point all their internal computers to this proxy server, and they want their public IP to be unique to THEM. Client B.) will point all their internal computers to the SAME server, but they want their public IP to be unique to them as well. So Client A.) may have 10 internal machines, but they want their public IP to come from my server. They also want to make sure this IP is just used by them. Client B, although pointing to the same server, needs to have a UNIQUE public IP on that server as well.

Comment: Maybe I don't need a "Proxy" per say, but this is the extent of the functionality I desire.  Thanks again for your insights.

Comment: per se not per say :)...been a long day.

Comment: You can do what you asked with RRAS; if you set up NAT for your network, you can configure the server with all your public IP addresses on its public interface, and tel it to "mask" each client behind a different public IP. But I'm still wondering why exactly would you want to do this... and why won't you directly give the public IPs to your clients, then.

Answer (score 0):

Routing and Remote Access Service may be too complex to configure. I suggest to use Kerio WinRoute Firewall (http://www.kerio.com/firewall). I was used it for 3 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I do have 10 public IPs on the server, and I can give the IPs directly to the clients.  The clients are able to use the server as a proxy using any of the public IPs I give them.  This already works.

The problem is that the server always reports itself as the first IP.  I didn't think this mattered, but I have several clients that insist on the IPs that the proxy reports being exclusive to them.  They don't want other people that go through that proxy to have the same IP they do.

Otherwise, I wouldn't even need the 10 IPs.  I'd just give all 10 clients one shared IP and be done with it.

I probably need to mask them as you suggest, but not sure how to do that.

The only other solution is to give one dedicated box to each client that requires an exclusive IP, but this is massive overkill considering one server can handle 100 clients with the small load I'm seeing...

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer to clarify your question, you should edit it.
Anyway, it's still not quite clear what you actually mean. What puzzles me the most is "the clients are able to use the server as a proxy using any of the public IPs I give them". How is your network configured? What is your gateway? Are you using a proxy software, and which one? Please, try to describe better what exactly is going on there.